# Importing Selected Column and Rows of Excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel, listview, datagridview

I'am using c# windows form and i'am import excelfile to listView, my reason that's why i'am using listview because for me it's more convenient for me and i'am comfortable with this data table.

So my question is how do i import selected columns and rows of excel file to listview? because my excel file have a format.

This is my Excel File.
In this picture i want to import all names and Quarterly grade to my listview.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQkaq.png)

This is my items in Listview

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KLm.png)
**This is my code for OpenFileDialog**

```
public static string path = "";
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Select file";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.FileName = txtFileName.Text;
        fdlg.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = textBox1.Text;
            txtFileName.Text = fdlg.FileName;

            Application.DoEvents();
        }



    }
```

**this is my code for importing excel data to listView**

```
    string Name = "";
            for (int b = 0; b < listView1.Items.Count; b++)
            {

                Name = listView1.Columns[1].Text;
                ListViewItem lvis = new ListViewItem();
                string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                string excelName = "2nd";
                string strConnection = string.Format(connStr);
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter oada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + excelName + "$]", strConnection);





                table.TableName = "TableInfo";
                oada.Fill(table);
                conn.Close();

                // Clear the ListView control
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                //for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                // Display items in the ListView control
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow drow = table.Rows[i];

                    // Only row that have not been deleted

                    if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                    {
                        // Define the list items
                        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["Quarter"].ToString());
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Male"].ToString());
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Female"].ToString());


                        // Add the list items to the ListView
                        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);




                    }
                }
```

If you guys suggest me to use datagrid well it's fine for me either as long it work well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is too much missing to reproduce the problem you describe. The posted code is confusing and I would recommend you try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE) for yourself. I can almost guarantee, that the process of creating this MCVE will reveal the problems you are having and if it doesn’t, then you will have something to post that others can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: One issue is the changing/altering of the number of items in a collection that is used in a loop’s ending condition. The code is “changing” the number of items in the collection while in the loop! It is confusing why you are looping through the list view control in the first place if you want to fill it with items from the excel file? Can you explain why the code is looping through the list view?

Comment: At the begging of the second code snippet, there is the `for` loop: `for (int b = 0; b < listView1.Items.Count; b++)` … Nothing special here, however, later “inside” this loop there is a line…`listView1.Items.Clear();`… then later `listView1.Items.Add(lvi);`… this is going to cause problems since the loops ending value is “changing” “inside” the loop. This will not work and you will need to use some other approach.